# Retrieving queries from webI reports in Business Objects

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Is it possible to retrieve the SQL queries from a report in business objects using the SDK.

Any tutorials or code would be useful.

regards,
nithen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you know how to get a WebI DocumentInstance object via the Java SDK.

```
DocumentInstance docInst; // get your DocumentInstance object via preferred route
DataProvider dp = docInst.getDataProviders().getItem(0); // retrieve the DataProvider that you would like the SQL for
String sql = dp.getQuery().getSQL(); // the SQL out of the DataProvider
```

getSQL() is depreciated so it may vanish in the next version